# Naming sublevels in aggregation function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

Using the next data I have aggregated both variables using different functions

```
data= pd.DataFrame({"Gender": ["M", "M", "M", "F", "F"],
                    "Math score": [7,3,8,9,5],
                    "Literature score": [10,7,5,8,8]})
data.groupby(["Gender"]).agg({"Math score": [np.min, np.max, lambda x: np.max(x)-np.min(x)], "Literature score": np.mean})
```

I got the next result
[Aggregation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qs8O.png)

The problem is I can´t rename the sub-column lambda_0 , or any other sub-column.
I have tried with tuples inside the list of functions with no result.

Comment: You should be using [`np.ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) instead of that lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pandas 0.25.0+ [renaming aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling) is possible and you don't have to deal with MultiIndex column headers.

```
data.groupby("Gender").agg(Math_min=('Math score','min'), 
                           Math_max=('Math score','max'), 
                           Math_diff=('Math score',np.ptp),
                           Lit_mean=('Literature score','mean'))
```

Output:

```
        Math_min  Math_max  Math_diff  Lit_mean
Gender                                         
F              5         9          4  8.000000
M              3         8          5  7.333333
```

---

I think lambda's not working in this format is a [reported bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28467).

```
data.groupby("Gender").agg(Math_min=('Math score','min'), 
                           Math_max=('Math score','max'), 
                           Math_diff=('Math score',lambda x: np.max(x)-np.min(x)),
                           Lit_mean=('Literature score', 'mean'))
```

Yields

```
KeyError: "[('Math score', '<lambda>')] not in index"
```

Should be fixed soon.

Comment: Please! choose this answer over mine (-:

Answer (score 3):

#### Define a function

```
def named_func(x):
    return np.ptp(x)

data.groupby(["Gender"]).agg(
    {"Math score": [np.min, np.max, named_func], "Literature score": np.mean}
)

       Math score                 Literature score
             amin amax named_func             mean
Gender                                            
F               5    9          4         8.000000
M               3    8          5         7.333333
```

Comment: ..or tuple! "Math Score": ['min', 'max', ('named_func', lambda s : (...))]`